# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))^{1+2\epsilon}}$ converge?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking through examples on convergences of random series, and in one of the proofs the following result is used: If $\epsilon > 0$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))^{1+2\epsilon}}<\infty$$

No explanation is given hence my confusion. I know that if $p>1$ then $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^p} < \infty$ but as this involes $\log(n)$, I do not understand how they reach this conclusion. Especially since $\sum_n \frac{1}{n(\log(n))}=\infty$.

Could someone explain how I would show this converges?

Comment: integral test against $\frac{1}{x\log(x)^{1+2\epsilon}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))^{1+2\epsilon}} \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n(\log(2^n))^{1+2\epsilon}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n\log(2))^{1+2\epsilon}}< \infty$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

You have

$$\int_2^x \frac{dt}{t (\log t)^{1+2\epsilon}} = \frac{1}{(\log x)^{2 \epsilon}}-\frac{1}{(\log 2)^{2 \epsilon}}$$

Proving that $$\int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{t (\log t)^{1+2\epsilon}}$$ converges. You can then use a [series / integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) comparison.